# Is it possible to use Laravel eloquent as a subquery of another Laravel eloquent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have USER table. A user is created by other user. So I want to get user's email base on the created user id.

```
$owner_email = User::select('email')->where('id', '=', function ($user) {
        User::select('created_by')->where('id', '=', $user->id);
    })->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

In your user model create relation like below

```
  public function owner(){

        return $this->hasone(User::class,'created_by','id');
    }
```

and in your query

```
$owner_email = User::with('owner')->select('email')->get();
```